Converting my time from hours:minutes into minutes when my time is in character format
I have a time currently in hours:minutes which I would like to convert into minutes. Now usually I think this can be done using the lubridate package and hms() function which enables us to get the hours and minutes out separately. However I'm struggling to do this as my time is in character format so just get an error, is there any way that I can convert my time into time format before doing this?
My current time I am trying to do this with is 1:24. I have had a look at trying to convert the time using:
strptime(mlength, format = "%H:%M")

However I'm a bit worried that this is more time on a 24h clock rather than a length of time.

hms() expects hour, minute, and second components. You have hour:minute, so try using lubridate::hm('1:24').

as.numeric(as.difftime(mlength, format='%H:%M', units='mins'))
Making sure to remove the seconds from the format argument else we return NA

as.difftime is really great, upvoted!

An approach that uses as.numeric on Period from lubridate
library(lubridate)

as.numeric(hm("1:24"), units="minutes")
[1] 84


Use read.table() and multiply the hours by 60.
> t(read.table(text=d$t, sep=':')) |> base::`*`(c(60, 1)) |> colSums()
[1]  84 141


Data:
> dput(d)
structure(list(t = c("1:24", "2:21")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
> d
     t
1 1:24
2 2:21

